# Can't install Rails on Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, installation

I want trying to install Rails using this guide - http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/

My last command was:

```
  gem install rails -v 3.2.3
```

Now, when I'm running

```
 rails new project
```

gives me errors:

```
 /home/denys/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': libcrypto.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/denys/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/digest/sha1.so (LoadError)
from /home/denys/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /home/denys/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/denys/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler.rb:144:in `definition'
from /home/denys/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler.rb:112:in `setup'
from /home/denys/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/setup.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/denys/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
from /home/denys/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
from /home/denys/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
from /home/denys/Desktop/pull/printitgreen/printitgreen/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/denys/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /home/denys/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from script/rails:5:in `<main>'
denys@denys-N68S3:~/Desktop/pull/printitgreen/printitgreen/script$ rails -v
 /home/denys/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems
 /custom_require.rb:36:in `require': libcrypto.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object 
file: No such file or directory - /home/denys/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1
 /i686-linux/digest/sha1.so (LoadError)
from /home/denys/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems
/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /home/denys/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler
/definition.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/denys/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler.rb:144:in `definition'
from /home/denys/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler.rb:112:in `setup'
from /home/denys/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/setup.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/denys/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
from /home/denys/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
from /home/denys/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
from /home/denys/Desktop/pull/printitgreen/printitgreen/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/denys/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /home/denys/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from script/rails:5:in `<main>'

 ---------------------------
```

More info:

```
    denys@denys-N68S3:~/Desktop$ rvm list

 rvm rubies

 ruby-1.9.2-p320 [ i686 ]
=* ruby-1.9.3-p194 [ i686 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

Comment: could you please provide the result of `rvm list`. Looks like you doesn't install `ruby-1.9.3-p194`

Comment: @ck3g, is it bad that now I'm trying another tutorial ?)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of the problem though, but [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NmWYZVUln4E) has helped me.

Comment: I'm trying to use another one tutorial. If it will fail I will try your video)

Answer (score 1):

looks like your ruby was not compiled with openssl support.

install `openssl-dev` and reinstall/recompile ruby

Answer (score 0):

Do you execute apt-get commands listed in tutorial?

Try:

sudo apt-get install libssl-dev