# Failed to find file when trying to create new Rails app on fresh Ruby installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, ubuntu-10.10

I'm using this guide - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm.

I know it is for 12.04, but it was reccomended by experienced user, so I used it.

I was following this guide and when I'm running:

```
  rvm install 1.9.3
```

I get in console

```
 denys@denys-N68S3:~/Desktop$ rvm install 1.9.3
 No binary rubies available for: ubuntu/10.10/i386/ruby-1.9.3-p194.
 Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary 
 rubies.
```

and then everything goes ok and tells me that installation is complete.

I followed all other instructions to the end. And now, when I'm running

```
  rails new project
```

I get errors in console:

```
  /home/denys/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': libcrypto.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/denys/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/digest/md5.so (LoadError)
from /home/denys/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /home/denys/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/denys/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /home/denys/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /home/denys/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/denys/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /home/denys/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /home/denys/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/application.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/denys/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /home/denys/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /home/denys/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/cli.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/denys/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /home/denys/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /home/denys/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/bin/rails:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/denys/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/rails:19:in `load'
from /home/denys/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/rails:19:in `<main>'
from /home/denys/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
from /home/denys/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

I think it is problem, because I'm trying to install and then Rails not working.

Please, help me with this.

Comment: Why do you create two questions which are actually the same? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12804112/cant-install-rails-on-ubuntu-10-10

Comment: Sorry, bad practice, but sometimes helped me)
I tried to install 12.04, 11.04(failed to run) and only 10.10 worked.

Answer (score 0):

Some Ruby libraries have external dependencies on some system libraries. For your error it seems what is missing is `openssl`.

If you type `rvm requirements` it will tell you what system libraries are required on your OS. For me in Ubuntu it says I need to install the following:

> apt-get install build-essential openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev automake libtool bison subversion pkg-config

Well... it does not mean you will necessarily need all of them - but some are absolutely necessary, like openssl/libssl, libxml etc

Comment: Я запускав цю команду. Все встановлено)/ Already run this command. All is installed.

Comment: `10.10` is kind of outdated version. I am not sure this is the case, but probably it has old, incompatible version of the necessary libs...